# Splitting an array with more then on value per field in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've created a Python numpy array with datatype object and filled it with the following datatype:

```
dtype =  np.dtype([('Tag',str)],[('Value',float)],[('Time', int)])
```

It is a 10,000 x 4 array. 3 rows with dtype the last one with a simple integer.
Now I want to reopen the array in a new file where only the value part of each array field is needed but sadly I'mm unable to split this up again.

Would be happy about a helpfull approach method or solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the 'Value' column of the array then:

```
a = np.array(your_list)
a[:,1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly that dosn't solve my Problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly that dosn't solve my problem. I want to get the 'Value' out of an array like with a row like this : [(['pv1', 350.89118399131047, 0]) (['pv2', 590.0906849913478, 0]) (['pv3', 413.89677735024156, 0]) 0]       if i try it like this : import numpy as np

b = np.load("alternatives array.npy",allow_pickle=True)

print(b[0,1][0])
i get 'pv2'. I would be happy if you also know how to do that the right way. Also sorry for the lack of struckture and my bad english I'm new here.

Comment: Hi Henry, try converting your whole array to an np array, I'll edit the code above.